# creating a container in a container with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, containers, getelementbyid

I would like to create a div-container in a div-container using AJAX and afterwards write "Hello World" in the inner container. The outer container has no special function. It just holds the inner container. This is my code:

**inex.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>

    <body>

        <div id="outerContainer"></div>        // this is my outer container

        <script>
            function request(){
                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                req.open("get", "response.php", true);
                req.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                        document.getElementById('outerContainer').innerHTML = this.responseText; 
                };
                req.send();
            }            
            request();

            // write "Hello World" in the inner container
            document.getElementById('innerContainer').innerHTML = "Hello World";
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

**response.php**

```
<?php
echo "<div id='innerContainer'>default text</div>";      // put this container inside the outer container
?>
```

After running the program I can see in the DOM that the inner div-container was created correctly inside the outer  div-container and that it's ID is 'innerContainer'. But writing "Hello World" in the inner container as I tried it doesn't work. Instead it's content is still 'default text'. The console outputs: "index.html:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null".

I would appreciate any suggestion or help.

Comment: I *think* that when the script is being run, innerContainer does not exist. Remember you are making an asynchronous request. Try putting ```document.getElementById('innerContainer').innerHTML = "Hello World";``` inside the if statement ```if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)``` so that it only executes once the innerContainer div has been generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried what I said in my comment and this works.

When you are running `document.getElementById('innerContainer').innerHTML = "Hello World";` in your code, this element likely does not exist (hence the 'null' error). You have to remember that you are making an asynchronous request. As such, other parts of the code will execute while the request is made.

One solution is to move the 'hello text' inside the response. So this works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>

    <body>

        <div id="outerContainer"></div>

        <script>
            function request(){
                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                req.open("get", "random.php", true);
                req.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                        document.getElementById('outerContainer').innerHTML = this.responseText;

                        document.getElementById('innerContainer').innerHTML = "Hello World";
                };
                req.send();
            }
            request();

        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the Hello World only is then inserted once the element actually exists. No chance of a non-existent div then.

Comment: If you have found it useful, then please upvote/accept it haha - I really want to bounty one of my own questions!

Comment: I did so. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>

<body>

    <div id="outerContainer"></div>        // this is my outer container

    <script>
        function request(){
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("get", "response.php", true);
            req.onreadystatechange=function(){
              if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                  document.getElementById('outerContainer').innerHTML = this.responseText; 

                  // write "Hello World" in the inner container
                  document.getElementById('innerContainer').innerHTML = "Hello World";
              };
            req.send();
        }            
        request();


    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, Shubham.